# Android place a Image below Text

Tags: android

I am using `drawableBottom` to place a image below text as a underline. But how do i get to stretch the image below to fit the text width. What is the easiest way to do this ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Instead of set drawableBottom just make one 9 patch image with top transparent  area and at bottom underline set this image as background image of TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

after initialising the TextView to get an underline, instead of using a drawable. (:

Hope this helps!

Comment: The underline image is a not a stright image, rather a red wavy one.

Comment: Or you could put both the TextView and the ImageView in a RelativeLayout, and then use the alignLeft and alignRight to make the ImageView alignment same as the TextView